# Vue warning: Unknown custom element

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

i had this error

```
app.js:3621 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <addvideo> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

my add-video.blade.php

```
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Add Video!</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <addVideo></addVideo>
    </div>
```

addVideo.vue

```
 <template lang="html">
  //template codes
</template>

<script>
export default {

  data(){

    return {
      errors:[],
      video : {
        name : '',
        rate : '',
        year : '',
        description : '',
        creator : '',
        director : '',
        writers : '',
        storyline : '',
        isMovie : '',
        season : ''
      }
    }


  },

  created(){
    this.fetchVideos();
  },

  methods:{
    fetchVideos(){
      axios.get('videos').then(response=>{

        this.video = response.data.video;
      });

    },
    addVideo(){

      axios.post('videos',this.videos).then(response =>{
        this.videos.push(response.data.video);
        this.video = {
          name : '',
          rate : '',
          year : '',
          description : '',
          creator : '',
          director : '',
          writers : '',
          storyline : '',
          isMovie : '',
          season : ''
        };
        console.log(response.data);
      },response=>{
          this.errors=response.data;
      });

    }

  }




}
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Users from './components/Users.vue';
import Register from './components/Register.vue';
import addVideo from './components/addVideo.vue';




window.axios = require('axios');


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components : { Users,Register,addVideo }
});
```

Laravel 5.4 project .I coded same code for different components.Same code works other component.I think have not syntax error.but i didn't find my fault.I hope shared piece of code helpful for you.

Comment: Try this `import AddVideo from './components/addVideo.vue';
Vue.component('addVideo',AddVideo)` and the same for others also `const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components : { //nothing here }
});`

Comment: I don't think so it's about that.i tried Vue.component('addVideo',require('./components/addVideo.vue')) but didn't work.@Cristy

Comment: @more I think somewhere else in your code you've added `<addvideo>` instead of `<addVideo>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, html tags are not case-sensitive, everything is lowered. Use  hyphen notation instead to have an equivalent to an `addVideo` in your template (as long as it is in a `.php` or an `.html` file):

```
<add-video></add-video>
```

Comment: That was the first thing that popped into my head as well

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about this before. Very helpful answer.